# Environment specific Google Analytics token with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I would like to have a certain config settings that would allow me to use different ga token per each environment (production, staging), I am using [this library](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/).

It has occurred to me to declare an angular constant with the token, but the problem is that I need the token already on the load event, and Angular only bootstraps after that event.

What would be a clean 'good practice' solution here.

Comment: Your Angular code can instantiate the Google Analytics code with the right token after Angular loads - then things can be clean as you wanted. Your question might be able to be rephrased - how do I get the missing events (which do you want? page-load?) into G.A. when I load G.A. via Angular?